# Insert, Update Triggers

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2012

I have a Table called `Couple` which has the following Fields `CoupleId, HusbandId , WifeId ,
StartDate , EndDate`

The previous Table contains informations about couple, The `CoupleId` is a primary key

`HusbandId` and `WifeId` are Foreign keys form another Table Named `Person`

`StartDate` and `EndDate` represent the start/end date of marriage that happens between a male with `HusbandId` and female with `WifeId`

in my problem i have a condition that w female can't married to two or more male at same time "Synchronous marriage"

and i have the following query

```
SELECT
   DISTINCT A.WifeID
FROM
   Couple A
   INNER JOIN Couple B
      ON A.WifeID = B.WifeID
      AND A.HusbandID <> B.HusbandID
      AND A.StartDate < B.EndDate
      AND A.EndDate > B.StartDate;
```

which returns any female who has Synchronous marriage " Married to two or more male at same time"

I want to write trigger which fire when somebody want to insert or update the `couple`
table ,and i want this trigger allow the modification only if it make no fault information on it ( for example if someone insert a row on couple table and this row make the wife with #4 married to tow or more person at same time, this insertion must not complete because it make wrong info in the table)

can any one help me at this point ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this without a trigger. Make a Composite primary key of these three keys in the `Couples` table like so:

```
PRIMARY KEY(CoupleId, HusbandId, WifeId)
```

This will ensure the uniqueness of the  `HusbandId` and `WifeId` for each `coupleId`.

Here is a demo for the schema design for these two tables:

[**SQL Fiddle Demo.**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1a90f)

---

If you want to do this using a TRIGGER, try this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER WhenInsertOrUpdate
ON Couples
INSTEAD OF INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
     IF (NOT EXISTS( SELECT c.CoupleId
                     FROM Couples c
                     INNER JOIN Inserted i  ON c.HusbandId = i.HusbandId
                                           AND c.WifeId = i.WifeId
                                           AND c.EndDate IS NULL))
    BEGIN
       INSERT INTO Couples
       SELECT  CoupleId, HusbandId, WifeId, StartDate, Enddate
       FROM Inserted
    END
    ELSE BEGIN
       --- You can put here an update..
    END

GO;
```

[Updated SQL Fiddle Demo using a trigger](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1b59d).

This is just an example, you have to provide an update statement in the `ELSE` block if you need.

Comment: Shouldn't that take the startDate and endDate into consideration somehow? A couple could be divorced and married more than once.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Yes, I noticed that. The OP didn't mention how this table is supposed to deal with this. I think it is better to move this into a new table in this case. And how about a new column `Status` as divorced or married be added to the composite key? but his won't work for more than one time marriage and divorce.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal Thanks, but I want to do it through a trigger because it's a request in HomeWork :) ... I searched to much about triggers but i didn't find any helpful tutorial :(

Comment: @MGCR7 OK, I will update my answer. But what about the startdate and enddate? If the enddate is null then the couple is still married and if this is not null then they are married?

Comment: @MahmoudGamal You are right, I suppose that the two dates are not null but it's better if I discuss the state that has a null enddate then the couple still married and if it's not null then the couple are not married

Comment: @MahmoudGamal thanks , but i have a question please, what the deference between the code after AS and the code After BEGIN , and what did you mean with  IF (NOT EXISTS ?

Comment: @MGCR7 - The `AS` is the beginning of the Trigger definition, but the `BEGIN` is the body of the `IF` statement. The IF NOT EXISTS ensure that the couple that will be inserted were not inserted before.

Comment: @MGCR7 Sorry it should be `IS NULL`

Comment: @MahmoudGamal ah thanks you :) here in your edit, when the condition if is TRUE .. it will insert the row in the Couple Table with in the Trigger,, but this trigger is Instead OF ..my question here when the trigger ends,, Dose SQL server make the insert statement again ??

Comment: @MGCR7 No It is only one insert or one update that is defined inside the trigger and it will insert only if the condition is true which mean that there are no husbandid or wifeid in presented in the couples table that had the same inserted values and there are still married.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal I mean with "Dose SQL server make the insert statement again" the insert statement that cause the Trigger to fire